# Comparing two version of the same string

Tags: regex, r, string

I would like to write a function that compare two string in R. More precisely, if a have this data :

```
data <- list(
  "First sentence.",
  "Very first sentence.",
  "Very first and only one sentences."
)
```

I would like the output to be :

```
[1] "Very"                    " and only one sentences"
```

My output is built by all substring that is not included in the previous one. For example:

2nd vs 1st, remove matching string - "first sentence." - from the 2nd, so result is "Very".

```
#       "First sentence."
#  "Very first sentence."
# match: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now compare 3rd vs 2nd, remove matching string - "very first" - from 3rd , so result is " and only one sentences".

```
#       "Very first sentence."
#       "Very first and only one sentences."
# match: ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then compare 4th vs 3rd, etc...

So based on this example my output should be:

```
c("Very", " and only one sentences")
# [1] "Very"                    " and only one sentences"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# put data in a data.frame
data_frame(string = unlist(data)) %>% 
    # add ID column so we can recombine later
    add_rownames('id') %>% 
    # add a lagged column to compare against
    mutate(string2 = lag(string)) %>% 
    # break strings into words
    separate_rows(string) %>% 
    # evaluate the following calls rowwise (until regrouped)
    rowwise() %>% 
    # chop to rows with a string to compare against,
    filter(!is.na(string2), 
           # where the word is not in the comparison string
           !grepl(string, string2, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>% 
    # regroup by ID
    group_by(id) %>%
    # reassemble strings
    summarise(string = paste(string, collapse = ' '))

## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##      id                  string
##   <chr>                   <chr>
## 1     2                    Very
## 2     3 and only one sentences.
```

Select out `string` if you'd like just a vector by appending

```
 ...
    %>% `[[`('string')

## [1] "Very"                    "and only one sentences."
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is that solution if there are more than one time the same word in the text (real data are much longer)

Comment: I tested it, and it doesn't not give the correct output if

`data <- list(
  "First sentence.",
  "Very first sentence. sentence.",
  "Very first sentence and only one sentences."
)`

Comment: Edited to follow your logic more directly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it seems to be not working again with to new input I give

Comment: How so? If it erroring out, or giving you incorrect results?

Comment: It doesn't take into account the adding of a second occurence of the word "sentence" in data[[2]]

Comment: What's it supposed to do in that case? Take out the first match but not the second? You could group so as to only evaluate repeated words once, but if you're talking about matching by different n-grams and taking out the maximal match, that would take a more serious text mining approach.

Comment: In fact I would like some git approach to make a version control.

Comment: here for instance you hae this kind of systems applied to a wikipedia article : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Glassy_carbon&diff=731510330&oldid=731510100

Comment: Version control and "diffing" are for multiple versions of the same file. That's not the data you've presented here. If that's what you've actually got, just use a [diff utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility).

Comment: do you kno ny diff utility implemented in R ?

Comment: In fact it was a data problem, and the approach suggested here worked. Sorry for disturb :(